# Determine if the integral is divergent or convergent

Tags: calculus

I should determine whether this is a convergent or divergent integral. The problem is that I don't know how to start.
$$
 \int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{x\ \sin(x)\ dx}{\sqrt{1+x^5}}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$\left \vert\dfrac{x \sin(x)}{\sqrt{1+x^5}} \right \vert \leq \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^5}} \leq \dfrac{x}{x^{5/2}} = \dfrac1{x^{3/2}}$$
Now you should be able to finish it off.

Comment: Garh, I was nearly there, but it felt wrong! Thank you!